# How to restrict motion to vertical in box2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, box2d, game-physics, physics-engine

I have a box2d body that has a fixture of a ball. It just bounces up and down on top of a rectangular box. Sometimes it will fall off of the box for no apparent reason. I there a way to restrict gravity to only vertical so that I can solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean with  fall of of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a prismatic joint. Check out this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vi2ymRwfAS0).

Answer (score 0):

Use b2LineJoint to allow your body to move in one direction only